# iOS: stopping webViewDidStartLoad

Tags: ios

Instead of letting webView to load the webpage, I want to add a new viewController to my application and load the URL instead.

How do I do this?

Currently, I put addSubView method in webViewDidStartLoad. The problem is, when I click on Back in the navigation bar, I go back to the same page that was loaded, so I have to click on Back 2 times before I go back to the page before I clicked on the link.

If I call webView stopLoading in webViewDidStartLoad, when I hit Back, I go back to a blank View.

Which method is called before webViewDidStartLoad gets called? Maybe I should override that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would try to do in `webViewDidStartLoad` is:

1) `popViewControllerAnimated:` in order to remove the `UIWebViewController`

2)  `pushViewController:animated:` to add the new view controller to the navigation stack.

This should get things in order.

EDIT: you can also try to add your logic to `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, which gives you the possibility of cancelling the loading by returning `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UIWebViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

> Sent before a web view begins loading
>   content